# Files unavailable when mouting the VOLUME with -v

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a Docker Image which has a VOLUME ["/log"].

While running the container I am mounting a folder present on the host.

I want all the logs written by  docker at VOLUME ["/log"] to be available to the host.

```
docker run --name=test -v ${pwd}/hostlogfolder:/log  dockerimage:1
```

The logs are not getting written to by hostlogfolder

But the logs are available inside docker at location /log

```
docker exec -it test bash
cd /log
```

What is the correct way to mount the folder?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, the command needs a small correction:

```
docker run --name=test -v $(pwd)/hostlogfolder:/log  dockerimage:1
```

Note that the brackets are different:
wrong: `${pwd}`
right: `$(pwd)`

Once running, you can verify the mounted volumes using:

`docker inspect <container id>`  -- you can get the container id using `docker ps`

Check the Mounts section of the command output.

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "<host path>",
                "Destination": "<container path>",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true
           }]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an image with predefined settings like add volume, then you have to use Dockerfile.  Or, if you don't need to create an image, but only need a temporary container to pass it when you create a container.

I think you need to read the documentation about creating volumes and other directives. It might be very useful for you.

```
docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Comment: I want to access the files written by Docker at location /log,which is a location I have mentioned in the Dockerfile using VOLUME ["/log"].
When I run docker inspect <container id>, I see two mounts the mount pointing to docker system file location and a mount pointing to the host path that I provided.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the mount point on the host with the VOLUME directive in Dockerfile?

Comment: ^ nvm I actually did some `docker inspect some-container | grep -e Source -e Destination` which had a `VOLUME["/some/dir"]` directive in its `Dockerfile`. I saw in `Destination -> /some/dir` and a automatically created directory on my host about here `/var/lib/docker/volumes/some-container-id/_data`. That explains it so far.